# Getting first letter from the string of first two words

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode9

My string like :

```
Apple recipe  recapes

Mango Tengaer

Lemone T U

Grapes limoenis  Steyic genteur
```

So what i tried is :

```
if let bakery = filtered?[indexPath.row]{
   let stringInput = bakery.fruitsname
                let stringInputArr = stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ")
                var stringNeed = ""

                for string in stringInputArr {
                    stringNeed = stringNeed + String(string.characters.first!)
                }

    print(stringNeed)  // have to print first word first letter, second word second letter

}
```

But for me crash on this line when i do for my 3rd `Lemone T U` words.On this line:

```
 stringNeed = stringNeed + String(string.characters.first!)
```

Any help !!

Thanks

```
Output i expect as per my above words


AR
MT
LT
GL
```

Comment: "My string like :" That's one string, or an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It separates the string into array of string and removes nil. So if the string has double space it filters that. Make sure that the string has minimum 2 words.

```
if let bakery = filtered?[indexPath.row]{
   let stringInput = bakery.fruitsname
   if stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ").count >= 2 {
         let stringNeed = (stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ").map({ $0.characters.first }).flatMap({$0}).reduce("", { String($0) + String($1) }) as NSString).substring(to: 2)
    print(stringNeed)  
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like better solution

Answer (score 3):

Just need to check the array count

```
var array =  [
"Apple recipe  recapes",
"Mango Tengaer",
"Lemone  T U",
"Grapes limoenis  Steyic genteur"]

for str in array {
    let wordArray = str.split(separator: " ")
    if wordArray.count >= 2 {
        let firstTwoChar = String(wordArray[0].first!)+String(wordArray[1].first!)
        print(firstTwoChar)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ar
MT
LT
Gl
```

Comment: Did your compile the code? It crashes in third object.

Comment: The out put is what i take out from my playground console, no crash whatsoever even with 2 space

Answer (score 1):

This should work for **Swift 4**

```
String(actualString.components(separatedBy: " ").compactMap { $0.first }).uppercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check optional for first letter Maybe there is extra space added to it

```
if let bakery = filtered?[indexPath.row]{
 let stringInput = bakery.fruitsname
        let stringInputArr = stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ")
        var stringNeed = ""

                for string in stringInputArr {

 //Check the optional
                if let first = string.characters.first{
                    stringNeed = stringNeed + String(first)

                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: (i have added prefix 2 so it will count only first 2 elements if there is only single element then don't worry it won't crash)

```
if let bakery = filtered?[indexPath.row]{
     let stringInput = bakery.fruitsname
            let stringInputArr = stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ")
            var stringNeed = ""

            for string in stringInputArr.prefix(2) //returns only first two elements {

             if let strFirst = string.characters.first{
                   stringNeed += String(strFirst)
               }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with keeping in fact that you have at start an array of String objects.

```
let myStrings:[String] = ["Apple recipe  recapes","Mango Tengaer", " Lemone T U", "Grapes limoenis", "Steyic genteur", "He"]

var retStr = "";
for (_, str) in myStrings.enumerated()
{
    let stringInOneLine = str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespaces).filter({$0.count > 0}).map({String($0.first!).uppercased()}).prefix(2).joined()

    //Separate all components by white spaces
    let c1 = str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    print("c1: \(c1)")

    //Remove components that are empty: It happens in case there is double spaces for instance
    let c2 = c1.filter({$0.count > 0})
    print("c2: \(c2)")

    //Get only the first letter and in upper case
    let c3 = c2.map({String($0.first!).uppercased()})
    print("c3: \(c3)")

    //Keep only the first two elements (if there is more or less than 2, it's takend care of
    let c4 = c3.prefix(2)
    print("c4: \(c4)")

    //Reform the String with the first letters
    let string = c4.joined()
    print("string: \(string)")



    retStr.append(stringInOneLine)
    retStr.append("\n")
    print("stringInOneLine:\n\(stringInOneLine)")
}

print("retStr:\n\(retStr)")
```

The way that is constructed `retStr` if need can be easily changed (if you want for instance an array of String).
I decomposed `stringInOnLine` construction by explaining why doing each calls.
It depends then on your Swift expertise level and global programming/algorithm skills to decide if you prefer the all chained in one line or do it in various lines.
It helps illustrate how do decompose chained calls (to either debug, understand or created them).

Answer (score 0):

that may seem a bit odd at first glance, but it actually does the job for you (I don't say it is the most efficient solution at all):

```
var input: [String] =  ["apple recipe recapes", "Mango Tengaer", "Lemone  T U", "Grapes   limoenis   Steyic genteur", "One", "A B"]
var result = input.filter { $0.contains(" ") && $0.characters.count > 0 }.map { String($0.first!).uppercased() + $0.substring(with: $0.range(of: "( \\w{1})", options: .regularExpression, range: $0.startIndex..<$0.endIndex)!).uppercased().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ")) }
```

and the actual `result` is:

```
["AR", "MT", "LT", "GL", "AB"]
```

---

***NOTE:*** it ignores the single words or empty strings, but you can extend it for those as well, I presume, quite easily if that is a requirement, it does not handle input strings with only spaces, as you may see in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you have just two words in a sentence.

```
String(fullName.components(separatedBy: " ").compactMap { $0.first })
```